# Angularjs Cannot read property '****' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Having trouble with ng-repeat hence it gives me an Cannot read property 'companyID' of undefined error in my .
Although this has been working on a previous version of angular. 
Cannot find the mistake in my code.

The console gives me these error, but I can see that i get the correct response from my API. 
[console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0wKt.png)

HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="companyCtrl">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-xl-8">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <th>Company ID</th>
              <th>Company Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Country</th>
              <th>Owners</th>
              <th>Phone number</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="company in companies" >
              <td>{{company.companyID}}</td>
              <td>{{company.companyName}}</td>
              <td>{{company.address}}</td>
              <td>{{company.city}}</td>
              <td>{{company.country}}</td>
              <td>{{company.owners}}</td>
              <td>{{company.phoneNumber}}</td>
              <td>{{company.email}}</td>

              <td><button class="btn" name="_method" ng-click="DeleteData($index)">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xl-3">
          <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="companyCtrl">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="companyID">Company ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyID" ng-model="companyID" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="companyName">Company Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" ng-model="companyName" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address">Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" ng-model="address" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="city">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="city" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="country">Country</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" ng-model="country" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="owners">Owners</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="owners" ng-model="owners" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phoneNumber">Phone number</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" ng-model="phoneNumber" optional>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="email" optional>
              </div>
                <button type="submit" id="popupContainer" class="btn" name="_method" ng-click="PostData($event)">Add</button>
            </form>

          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  <button ng-click="Refresh()">Refresh test</button>
</div>
```

script:

```
myApp.controller('companyCtrl',function($scope,  $http, $window) {
   $http.get("https://***.herokuapp.com/api/v1/companies").then(function (response) {
    $scope.companies = response.data;
    console.log("Data response: ");
    console.log(response.data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you nesting `ng-app="myApp"`? remove inner `ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="companyCtrl"`

Comment: @Satpal doesn't make any difference. actually it makes my code work :) 
I tried to remove them but still the same error.

Comment: did you try printing the **companies** list as a whole? Just to check if the companies are defined in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

check console error , Unexpected token  : which is breaking the script causing that companyID error.

Comment: still the same problem even though unexpected token has been fixed.
https://i.imgur.com/w5v54TS.png

Answer (score 0):

You can handle null check for prevents from error throws

`<td ng-if="company && company.companyID">{{company.companyID}}</td>`

for all these properties.

Comment: Just tried to move my code into index.html in angular instead of app.component.html.Here code works flawless. Still can't find the bug

Comment: just tried your solution/idea same result with the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the page is trying to render the ng-repeat before the promise is being resolved. Try putting a ng-if in the table or in the tr to see if this solves the problem.

```
<table ng-if="companies" class="table table-striped table-hover">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try define $scope.companies = []; in your script code before $http.get